# How to manually calculate the max $n$ s.t. $n!<100^{n-1}$?

Tags: computational-complexity

Is it possible to calculate the maximum interface value for $n$ so that $n!<100^{n-1}$, without using computer or calculator? I thought of using Sterling but

$$\ln n! = n \ln n - n + 1/2 \ln (2 \pi n) + 1/(12n) - ... $$
Needs calculating $\ln n$, not so easy seems

Comment: Yes, it is possible: using a lot of ink and paper.

Comment: Steirling formula is good to replace instead of $n!$

Comment: @MyGlasses pls see my post updated

Comment: In this case not using a calculator seems rather senseless. Why are you trying to compute this by hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd take $\ln$ of both sides.  Then the left side is

$$\sum_1^n \ln n \approx \int_1^n \ln x \; dx = n\ln n - n +1$$

which needs to be less than $(n-1)\ln 100$.  So

$$\frac{n}{n-1}\ln n - 1 < \ln 100 = 4.605.$$

You have to grind out $\ln 100$ using Taylor series. Then use $\frac{n}{n-1} \approx 1$ and we have $n\approx e^{5.605}.$  Another Taylor series calculation gives $n = 271.78.$  The right answer is $n=270$, so we got pretty dang close.